# How do we add removable concrete plinth protection to an existing building

Tags: concrete, drain, foundation, waterproofing, water-damage

There is a short concrete wall and there's building main wall.

[image]

The water collects between the gap and this goes into the foundation.

I want to build the **plinth protection** above the height of Short concrete wall so that water doesn't pool between the short wall and building main and go into the foundation.

I have plumbing lines going between the building main wall and a short concrete wall as you can see in the picture below.

[image]

Because there's a plumbing line going between the walls I have to make the plinth protection removable so that when there's a problem I don't have to destroy the plinth protection to fix the problem in plumbing lines

Comment: I don't think this is common in north america.  We generally manage water with gutters, downpipes, perimeter drains, storm drains and soil graded away from the house.  Dimple fabric or waterproofing for exterior of foundation walls in ground contact.  We often pour concrete side walks on one side of the house anyway but not all sides.

Comment: What's with the pic of the trench drain?

Comment: @Huesmann - the pics are model pics shows a plinth protection which also act as drain for the wall. I'd like to do the same but I want to do this removable so that I can work beneath like applying bitumen to the foundation once in 10 years or work with any faulting plumbing.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger - The rain that falls on terrace or top floor is collected and led far away from the building foundation. But When it rains the rain falls heavily on the exterior walls of the building also and this water goes into foundation so I'm looking for a plinth protection kind of like structure which also has small trench so the water can be redirected to the drainage line

Comment: If you want something up against the foundation, but you also want to waterproof the foundation, then do the foundation waterproofing _first_, then build your plinth. Look into something other than bitumen - I'm not aware of any foundation waterproofing methods used in North America that require refreshing every decade. They're usually "install and forget for a century" type products.

Comment: I understand makes sense.It's not just about applying bitumen but also there are plumbing pipe lines that needs to be looked at when plumbing goes bad. That's why I want to keep this easy to removable

Comment: Put sleeves around any pipes that will penetrate the foundation. That way, if plumbing ever needs to be replaced, you can excavate either side of the foundation and slide the old, broken pipe out and a new pipe in. That's what I did 30 years ago when the concrete guys dug through my main drain while excavating for a new foundation. I haven't had to touch that PVC line in the ensuing 30 years, though. It appears that you're in India - maybe building materials there are different in construction/quality than they are here in the US. Maybe indicate the type(s) of pipe you'll be using.

Comment: @FreeMan - Here we're using Finolex PVC pipes , it's known to be bit expensive and relatively high quality.

Comment: @FreeMan - My plumbing lines are running like just 4 to inches from the ground level , if I ever have to fix. The easiest way is dig ,little bit between the short wall and building main wall .. What I'm thinking . I'd just remove the earth till the plumbing lines and place removable plinth protection so the when the rain batters the water that comes down by hitting the wall, will  be collected and led away using the plinth protection and when I want to work on the plumbing line just remove the plinth protection and work on it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm fresh out of ideas for you. Maybe edit some of the details from these comments into your question so someone looking at it again will have a better picture without having to scan through all this conversation (most won't). TBH, a significant number of people answering these questions are in the US, and what you're asking about just doesn't happen here, so your pool of possible answerers familiar with your situation is pretty small at this site. Maybe talk with local contractors/DIYers to see what's done locally...

Comment: @FreeMan - I have updated the question to make it easy to understand. Because US also has warmer regions , your innovative ideas to solve the problem is good. Some of the problems are same.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger - Do you think I can set up a removable perimeter drain here ?